# How do you render an SVG with the F# Giraffe library

Tags: svg, f#, f#-giraffe

I need to render an SVG file in my html.

[The documentation hasn't gotten me there](https://github.com/giraffe-fsharp/Giraffe.ViewEngine?tab=readme-ov-file#rendering-xml).

I want to pull the SVG from an embedded file

```
open System.IO
open System.Reflection

[<AbstractClass; Sealed>]
type Assets private () =
    static let assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()

    static let readSvgResource fileName =
        use stream =
            assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"Namespace.Assets.Svg.{fileName}.svg")

        use reader = new StreamReader(stream)
        reader.ReadToEnd()

    static member DownArrow =
        readSvgResource "downArrow"
```

Then have a nice function that I can reuse. This is where I'm am stuck and it doesn't compile. What should this function be?

```
let renderSvg color (assetsSvg: string) = 
     div [ _style $"color: {color}" ] [ RenderView.AsString.xmlNode assetsSvg ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should wrap the raw SVG text in the `rawText` Giraffe function, then render the entire HTML page/fragment/etc using one of the `RenderView` module's functions. Here's a simple worked example that takes a raw SVG string and writes it to an HTML document:

```ml
let svgtext =
    """
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path d="M30,1h40l29,29v40l-29,29h-40l-29-29v-40z" stroke="#000" fill="none"/> 
  <path d="M31,3h38l28,28v38l-28,28h-38l-28-28v-38z" fill="#a23"/> 
  <text x="50" y="68" font-size="48" fill="#FFF" text-anchor="middle"><![CDATA[410]]></text>
<script xmlns="" id="bw-fido2-page-script"/></svg>
"""

open Giraffe.ViewEngine

let svg color (assetsSvg: string) =
    div [ _style $"color: {color}" ] [
        rawText assetsSvg
    ]

svg "red" svgtext
|> RenderView.AsString.htmlDocument
|> fun s -> System.IO.File.WriteAllText("svg.html", s)
```